# Show that a localization a power series ring $R[[x]]$ by $S$ can be written a certain way.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, laurent-series, localization

I had to shorten the title because the whole thing wouldn't fit. I'll write the full question here and show my thoughts below.

> For a commutative ring $R$, consider the power series ring $R[[x]]$ and the submonoid $S=\{x^n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ of $(R[[x]],\cdot)$ generated by $x$, let $R((x))$ be the localization $S^{-1}R[[x]]$. $R((x))$ is called a *Laurent series* ring over $R$, and its elements are called Laurent series.
>
> Show that the elements of $R((x))$ may be written as $$\sum_{i=m}^\infty a_ix^i$$ where $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $a_i\in R$. (*Note*: $m$ represents a lower bound for the nonzero coefficients of a given series, but different series may have different values of $m$.)

I need a lot of help. When I'm not sure where to start, I usually just write down what I know...

I know that the power series ring $R[[x]]$ is the set of all polynomials like so $\{a_0, a_0 + a_1x, a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2, \dots \}$. I know that $S$ is written out as $\{1, x, x^2, \dots \}$. I *think* I know the *localization* of $R[[x]]$ at $S$ is the "smallest" ring in which elements of $S$ become invertible. That is to say that $R((x))=S^{-1}R[[x]]$ is the smallest ring that makes $S$ invertible (do I have that right?). If that's the case, then I need the set of things that take elements of $S$ to the identity $(1,0,0, \dots)$.

So if I start with $n=0$, that's already the identity, so I'll need the identity $(1,0,\dots) \in R((x))$. If $n=1$ (that's $x$) so I'll need $x^{-1} \in R((x))$. For $x^k$, I will need $x^{-k} \in R((x))$. I haven't gotten to the part where I am able to write elements of $R((x))$ as how I want it, but am I on the right track in my initial thinking?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There are a couple definitions of localisation. What you are describing is a universal property. One can also define localisations similar to how we define fraction fields: $\frac{a}{s} = \frac{b}{t}$ where $a,b \in R[[t]], s,t \in S$ if $r(at - bs) = 0$ for some $r \in S$. Since $R[[t]]$ is a domain and $0 \notin S$, $r(at - bs) = 0$ is the same as $at - bs = 0$ which is the usual relation we have for fractions. This also implies that we can think of $S^{-1}R[[t]]$ as being contained in the fraction field of $R[[t]]$. Incidentally, this fraction field is $R((t))$.

Comment: The question I have for you is: how do you want to think about $S^{-1}R[[t]]$ for the purpose of this question? A more concrete definition tends to be easier to work with than a more abstract one.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think you’re thinking of elements of $R[[x]]$ in the most productive way. Just think of them as the kind of series you dealt with in Calculus, but not as functions, just as (usually) infinite expressions of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$. Make sure you understand, for example, why the element $1-x\in R[[x]]$ has for its reciprocal the element $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\in R[[x]]$.

Now, when you make the single element $x$ invertible in the extension ring, you get things like $x^{-3} +2x^{-1}-1+3x^3-x^4$, just as an example of a series with finitely many terms; and you should persuade yourself that the reciprocal of $x^m(1-x)$ is $\sum_{n=-m}^\infty x^n$.

Once you are comfortable dealing with power series, the concept of Laurent series will come fairly easily to you.

Comment: "Make sure you understand, for example, why the element $1−x∈R[[x]]$ has for its reciprocal the element $1+x+x2+x3+⋯∈R[[x]]$".


That's pretty cool. I wrote out the statement and distributed, and they all cancel out to give me 1 + 0 + 0 + ... The identity!

I'm still trying to convince myself that the reciprocal of $\frac{x^m}{1-x}$ is $\sum_{n=-m}^\infty x^n$. When I write it out, I get $\frac{x^m}{1-x} (x^{-m}+x^{-m+1}+x^{-m+2}+ \dots)$. From there, I distribute the $x^m$ which gives me $\frac{1}{1-x}(1+x+x^2+ \dots)$. Do I need to refresh my knowledge of long division of polynomials?

Comment: Oh, my strongest apologies. I wrote very carelessly. I meant to write “the reciprocal of $x^m(1-x)$”, and will now change that.

Comment: That makes more sense now. Thank you.